# Can boilerplate text be made conditional on a field value when generating RTF documentation from EA?

Tags: rtf, enterprise-architect

Using EA 9.3.930 I'm trying to generate a document which I don't have to hand edit lots afterward.

I've an element section where I want to show

PackageName::ElementName extends BaseClasses

This is fine where there is a base class, but I can't get rid of the "extends" when there isn't a base class defined.

My template fields look like this:

{Element.ParentPackage}::{Element.Name} extends {Element.BaseClasses}

Is it possible to make the "extends" dependent on a non-null Element.BaseClasses value?

Answer (score 0):

Not in that structure, no. You can't make a fixed text depend on whether a field has a value.

But if you change the template so that you output the results in a table instead, it should be doable. You would then use, say "{Element.ParentPackage}::{Element.Name} Base Classes" as a document heading (not the table header row) and place {Element.BaseClasses} on the table row. I'm pretty sure that if there are no base classes, no table would be generated at all - but you'd still need to edit the document manually to get rid of the headings.

If you use a master document / model document structure, you could create two model documents, one with {Element.ParentPackage}::{Element.Name} extends {Element.BaseClasses}, and one with {Element.ParentPackage}::{Element.Name}.

You could then create searches which retrieve only those classes which respectively have, and do not have, base classes and hook those up to either model document.

Instead of using the SearchName tag in the model document, you can set filters in the respective templates themselves; however, I'm not sure whether this ability was introduced in EA 10 (Document Options dialog, Custom Query tab).

It's difficult to be more specific without seeing the whole template structure, but one of the above approaches should work. In EA 10 you could achieve the effect using template fragments, but those are definitely not available in EA 9.